# Rotating output of a laptop display

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I've got a laptop with an nVidia card in it and I want to rotate the output 180 degrees. The driver doesn't support this but is there a utility that will enable it?

Comment: What operating system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most nVidia drivers have this built in.  Actually have not seen one without this fuctionality

Comment: Yes, it's in the advanced settings.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a Windows laptop you can try control+alt and the arrow keys on the toolbar. This is a built in Windows feature.

Comment: This feature is not built into windows (at least not in XP or Vista) but comes with both Intel and Nvidia display drivers (maybe others as well)

Answer (score 0):

I have NVIDIA NVS 3100M graphics card on ThinkPad T410.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and the arrow keys doesn't work when NVIDIA card is running.  I wish it does.

When the integrated Intel graphics takes over, the hotkey does work.